# iphonexs max crash, and it always happened when the app go back from background to foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, cggradientref

the crash  only happened on iPhone XS MAX  and  go back from background  to foreground

```
[CAGradientLayer _clearContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2815c31a0

CoreFoundation  ___exceptionPreprocess + 232

1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 60

2 CoreFoundation    -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]

3 CoreFoundation    ____forwarding___ + 1412

4 CoreFoundation    _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96

5 UIKitCore -[UILabel _startMarquee] + 3332

6 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32

7 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_client_callout + 20

8 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1012

9 CoreFoundation    ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16

10 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 1888

11 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452

12 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 108

13 UIKitCore    UIApplicationMain + 216

14 ÈáëÂõø   main (main.m:14)

15 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4
```

Is it killed already during background, just iPhone XS max has different refelection.

Comment: Without code its difficult to help you

Comment: I could not find  what code cause the crash

Comment: Put exception breakpoint and check

Comment: find your CAGradientLayer related code in app and put here.

Comment: I have not iphonexs max , and before I tested it , I could not make the application crash , and other kinds of iphones did not crash. Is there any possibility that the category of UIView with CAGradientLayer cause the problem.

Comment: the category code is: